# Render function return html generated on certain DOM element Apache Echarts

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, echarts

I have this situation, I need to return an echart from Apache echarts in Typescript in a render function like this:

```
renderHTML(): {
  return '<div>....';
}
```

But the chart is generated directly on the DOM object with the following function:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
```

And I can't use this syntax because I don't have the final DOM, that will be generated by another platform afterwards.

I tried creating a DOM element and giving it as argument to echarts.init(), but it does not work because inside the function, it will search for the real DOM element on runtime and that does not exist.

Any options to generate a string response for the renderHTML function from the echarts.init()?

Thanks